# Add Object to List after orElse

Tags: java, lambda

```
inscTipoTrabAval.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestoes()
    .stream()
    .filter(aq -> aq.getEventoQuestao().equals(eventoQuestao))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(new InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao(eventoQuestao, inscTipoTrabAval))
    .setJustificativa(justificativa);
```

I'm trying to write an object into a list if it doesn't exist with orElse, but it isn't adding to the list. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Where would your code try to add anything to the list? `orElse()` will return a default value but there won't be any add. Assuming `getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestoes()` returns that list you might want to use something like `orElseGet(() -> { var x = new InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao(eventoQuestao, inscTipoTrabAval); getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestoes().add(x); return x;})`

Comment: It'll be a good idea to just break this up into two or more statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to store the list in a variable, and check the content of your optional

```
//assuming the list is not immutable
List<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao> list = inscTipoTrabAval.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestoes();
list.stream()
    .filter(aq -> aq.getEventoQuestao().equals(eventoQuestao))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        existing -> existing.setJustificativa(justificativa),
        () -> {
            var value = new InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao(eventoQuestao, inscTipoTrabAval));
            value.setJustificativa(justificativa);
            list.add(value);
        }
    );
```

If you're on Java 8, you can use an `if` block

```
Optional<InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao> value = list.stream()
    .filter(aq -> aq.getEventoQuestao().equals(eventoQuestao))
    .findFirst()

if(value.isPresent()) {
    value.get().setJustificativa(justificativa);
} else {
    InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao newValue = new InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAvaliadorQuestao(eventoQuestao, inscTipoTrabAval));
    newValue.setJustificativa(justificativa);
    list.add(newValue);
}
```